# Count rows with more equal cells just once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

For example I have this table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class ="mark">1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class ="mark">4</td>
        <td class ="mark">5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now I want to count **how many rows have cells with class "mark"**.
I can use something like this (with jQuery):

```
$('.mark').length;
```

But it gives me number 3 (in example table), but there are only 2 rows with this class.
There is any elegant solution how to achieve this?

Comment: `.parents("tr").length`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `parent()`.

try this

```
$('.mark').parent().length;
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/XtGQt/)

Comment: welcoem...:).. glad it helped.. happy coding. ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
$('.mark').parent('tr').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
$('.mark').closest('tr').length;
```

This will also work for cases when `mark` is deeply nested.